# React-native, monorepo: Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg, monorepo

I've set up a react-native app as workspace in a monorepo.  I did this because I want to share some react components I've created between my mobile and web apps.

The basic structure of my repo is:

```
root/
    package.json (with nohoist: ["**/expoapp/**"])
    modules/
        ...shared modules, some simple JS, some react
    apps/
        web/  (cra-based web app)
        mobile/
            package.json
            metro.config.js (addes watchFolders and extraNodeModules)
            App.js
```

I am able to import simple JS modules into my mobile app from the modules directory.

But when I try to import one of my react components, I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from /Users/jim/development/.../modules/dumb-module/index.js: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project.
```

The error message in the console points to the first line of my react component:

```
iOS Bundling failed 3378ms
Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from /Users/jim/development/.../modules/dumb-module/index.js: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
> 1 | import React from 'react';
  2 |
  3 | const DumbModule = () => {
  4 |     return (
```

`DumbModule` is an intentionally simple react component:

```
import React from 'react';

const DumbModule = () => {
    return (
        <div>I am useless.</div>
    );
};

export default DumbModule;
```

I add it to App.js like so:

```
import DumbModule from '@mymodules/dumb-module';
```

The dependencies in my react-native app are:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

If I disable the import into App.js, the app runs fine.  If I enable it, I get the above message pointing at the first line of my component.

I've been through every suggestion I can find.  No luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We were able to work around this problem by adding the path to the project's `node_modules` directory to the `nodeModulesPaths` array in `metro.config.js`.  It would appear that when metro is resolving the dependencies of the external module (dumb-module) it didn't automatically know to look in the project's own `node_modules`, so it couldn't find react.

Of course, it would have been helpful if the error message didn't refer to an unrelated babel file.

Here's my updated `metro.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

const extraNodeModules = {
    'modules': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../../modules'))
};

const watchFolders = [
    path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../../modules'))
];

const nodeModulesPaths = [path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, './node_modules'))];

module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: true,
                inlineRequires: true,
            },
        }),
    },
    resolver: {
        extraNodeModules,
        nodeModulesPaths
    },
    watchFolders
};
```

Comment: this works for me but replacing `'../../modules'` for `'../../node_modules'`

Comment: I just needed to add `../../node_modules` into `watchFolders` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

With react-native 0.73, I had to update `metro.config.js` code by adding `../..` to the `config.watchFolders` :

```js
const path = require('path');
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const config = {
  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../')],
};
module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```