# How to use path alias for a folder outside project root in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs, tsconfig, metro-bundler

I'm working on a React Native project that's part of a wider project with multiple packages. The folder structure of the project is as follows (excluding most of the irrelevant files):

```
monorepo
└── packages
    ├── backend
    ├── frontend-app
    │   ├── babel.config.js
    │   ├── metro.config.js
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── src
    └── shared
        └── data-types.ts
```

Inside the `frontend-app` folder, I want to be able to import types from the `data-types.ts` file. Additionally, I want to do this by using `@shared/data-types` rather than having to use a relative path `../../shared/data-types` (or even more folders up).

I was able to find only that you have to update the `babel.config.js` and `tsconfig.json` for regular path aliases inside the app project itself, but when running the app I still get a warning like this:

```
Unable to resolve module ../../../../shared/data-types from ***: 

None of these files exist:
  * ../shared/data-types(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ../shared/data-types/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

[...]
```

How to make it work for files outside of the React Native project's folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Path aliases are incredibly useful for cleaner imports and avoiding relative path hell in larger projects. While they're commonly used within a project, sometimes there's a need to alias paths outside the React Native project root, especially in monorepos or when sharing code across multiple projects.

To make path aliases work for files/folders outside of the React Native app's project root, you have to modify the `babel.config.js`, `tsconfig.json`, and the `metro.config.js` files.

Given the directory structure where your React Native project and the `shared` folder are sibling directories (i.e., they have the same parent directory), here's how you can set up the path alias:

**1. Install the required dependency:**
First, you need to add a development dependency to your React Native project to help Babel resolve the aliases.

Using npm:

```bash
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Or using yarn:

```bash
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

**2. Configure your files:**

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        extensions: [".ios.js", ".android.js", ".ios.jsx", ".android.jsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        root: ["."],
        alias: {
          "@shared": "../shared",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Other settings
    "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
    },
    // Other settings
  },
  "include": ["./src/*", "../shared/*"]
}
```

**metro.config.js**

```js
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config");
const path = require("path");

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname + "/../shared")],
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

Once you've made these changes, make sure to restart the Metro bundler. If you encounter any issues, resetting the cache can help: `npx react-native start --reset-cache`.

With these changes, you'll be able to seamlessly import from the `@shared` alias in your React Native app.

You can present this additional information as an update or a postscript to your original answer. Here's a possible format:

---

**Update:**

After implementing the above, I discovered that while everything works perfectly in development, local builds, and archives, there was an issue when trying to build using Fastlane on a remote machine (specifically, Azure DevOps pipelines). The error manifested during the build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images', resulting in a Fastlane exit code 65. The underlying error in the `xcodebuild` logs pointed to: "Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault" within the `shared` package. This error hinted that the `node_modules` could not be located within the shared package.

Thankfully, I stumbled upon this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354685/6937779) that provided a solution. The gist of the solution was an update to the `metro.config.js`. Note, this solution may not be necessary for everyone, but it resolved my specific issue.

```js
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config");
const path = require("path");

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const extraNodeModules = {
  shared: path.resolve(__dirname + "/../shared"),
};

const watchFolders = [path.resolve(__dirname + "/../shared")];

const nodeModulesPaths = [path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "./node_modules"))];

const config = {
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules,
    nodeModulesPaths,
  },
  watchFolders,
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

Comment: you also have to include your shared directory in the include section of tsconfig

Comment: Good one - I did this but forgot to include it in the answer. Updated now.